# Is it possible to make a 'junit test' and 'network request message' mapping table without modifying code?

Tags: java, junit, network-programming, packet-sniffers

Problem:
I do not know which test case actually covers codes related to network connection. Also, I want to know the content of the network request message. But I don't want to add some log-generating codes to the original program.

Goal:
Automatically make a junit test and network request message mapping table without modifying codes.

For example,

test2 - https://www.google.com/search?q=apple

test5 - https://twitter.com/search?q=justin+bieber

I guess there should be a technology monitoring junit test and network together. But I am not an expert in programming.

Answer (score 0):

spring has the solution connecting the junit and web request. 
please refer to this class

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```